# Reference all the arguments in Julia

Tags: julia

Is it possible to capture all the arguments and pass it to another function?

To make code like that shorter:

```
function send_binary(;
  binary_hash::String,
  binary::String
)::Any
  post_json(
    "http://localhost:$(port)/v1/binaries",
    json((binary_hash=binary_hash, binary=binary))
  )
end
```

(theoretical) Shorter version:

```
function send_binary(;
  binary_hash::String,
  binary::String
)::Any
  post_json("http://localhost:$(port)/v1/binaries", json(arguments))
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [splat operator](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#...) [captures arguments](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/faq/#...-combines-many-arguments-into-one-argument-in-function-definitions-1) in function definitions and [interpolates arguments](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/faq/#...-splits-one-argument-into-many-different-arguments-in-function-calls-1) in function calls:

```
julia> bar(; a=0, b=0) = a, b
bar (generic function with 1 method)

julia> foo(; kwargs...) = bar(; kwargs...)
foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> foo(; a=1, b=2)
(1, 2)

julia> foo()
(0, 0)

julia> foo(; b=1)
(0, 1)
```

Your example can be written as:

```
function send_binary(; kwargs...)
  return post_json("http://localhost:$(port)/v1/binaries", json(; kwargs....))
end
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know if it would be possible to provide types for splat arguments?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
using Plots

function myplot(func;moreargs...)
    plot([k for k = 0:0.01:2*pi],[func(k) for k = 0.0:0.01:2*pi];moreargs...)
end

myplot(sin,legend=false)
myplot(x->(sin(x)+cos(x)),legend=false)
```